# How to stopping auto scrolling after submitting the form?

Tags: forms, bbpress, forum

After submitting the form the pages get loaded and the scroll goes up automatically the user has to scroll down to see the message. Can we disable the scroll?

Below is the url on which i facing the issue

http://www.wavesstrategy.com/forums/topic/nifty-neo-wave-training-queries/
http://www.wavesstrategy.com/free-member-login/

After filling the form on the above page the scroll goes up

Answer (score 0):

Stopping auto scrolling after submitting the form

1. **wp dequeue script** OR **wp deregister script** this js **scroll-scripts.js**

Please check it this link :  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/

I hope is usefull

Comment: Can you tell me how to do ?

Comment: provide the link for wp dequeue script.